# Need help identify error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_hashlib.HASH' and 'bytes'

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, hashlib

Below is a part of my code

```
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
```

...

```
  def pad(s):
        # Add \x00 (byte) to the end of s to make the len is multiply of AES.block_size
        return s + b"\0"*(AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)


  def encrypt(key,plaintext):
        # padding original text
        padtext = pad(plaintext)
        
        # Choose a random, AES.block_size.
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)

        # Create AES-CBC cipher based on key and iv
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        
        # Encrypt pad text
        en_cipher = cipher.encrypt(padtext)
        
        # Create checksum
        cs = hashlib.md5(en_cipher).digest()

        return cs + iv + en_cipher
```

It runs on my laptop, but when I run it on another PC I got this error:

```
return cs + iv + en_cipher
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_hashlib.HASH' and 'bytes'
```

I think I miss to install a package but I am not sure what it is. I cannot find this error anywhere.

Comment: Which Python versions run on the computers, and which libraries (i.e. is PyCrypto or PyCryptodome used)? The latter question especially with regard to your `pad` method. The modern PyCryptodome supports padding with an own module, but the `pad` method expects the block size as 2nd argument. Since your `pad` expects only the plaintext, it seems that a custom padding is used.

Comment: I use the same version of Python 3.6.8 on both machines and use PyCryptodome. I updated the code above.

Comment: The error message occurs for example if the `digest()` call is missing, i.e. when only `cs = hashlib.md5(en_cipher)` is called and `cs` is then concatenated with a bytes object (like `iv`). Possibly a copy / paste error? Otherwise I unfortunately have no explanation (except maybe a problem with the Python installation on the computer in question).

Comment: You are right. By some reason, my code is modified and it misses the digest() call in another PC.